# navigation/load different views on WPF/MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, view, navigation

I am quite new to WPF development, and currently I am trying to use the MVVM on my application development. I have read a lot about MVVM navigation and switching views, but I can't find a solution for my current situation. Let's explain what it is:
First of all, I have my main View element, a Dockpanel, with some fixed areas, and a main "dynamic" area where the content should change, depending on actions:

```
<DockPanel>
    <Label Content="Top Fixed element"/>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Height="auto" Width="150" DockPanel.Dock="Left">
        <Label Content="SomeOptions"/>
        <!-- some more elements -->
    </StackPanel>
    <Label DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Content="Foot"/>        
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentMainViewElementViewModel}"/>        
</DockPanel>
```

I have defined some DataTemplates that I would like to load in this ContentControl, here there is one of the Data Templates as example:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModel:FileLoaderVM}">
        <View:FileLoaderView/>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```

This FileLoader (View and View Model are implemented, using the RelayCommand and the INotifyPropertyChanged) opens a dialog box after clicking a button, where after selecting a file it is opened and parsed, and show all the found elements inside a ListView with multiple selection(in this case, persons with their data).
What I want to do now is to load another user control in this ContentControl, when I click a button. This button is defined in my view model like this:

```
public ICommand LoadPersons
    {
        get { return new RelayCommand(param => this.loadSelectedPersons(), param => (SelectedPersons!=null && SelectedPersons.Any()));}
    }
```

My question comes at this point, how can I modify the content of the ContentControl, loading another User Control instead of the current one directly from my view model (in this "this.loadSelectedPersons()")?
If this is not possible, how should I approach to solve this problem?
Next to this action, I want to show all the previously selected elements and manipulate in different possible ways (inserting in a DB, saving in another file and so on), and I have already for that the appropriate User Control, that I would like to show in my main view element in the ContentControl section, keeping the other elements as they are originally.

Comment: You're returning a new ICommand every time the property is accessed?  That's not right at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lets see if i get you right.

you have a mainviewmodel with a property (CurrentMainViewElementViewModel) bound to the ContentControl. your MainViewmodel set the FileLoaderVM to this Property. now you wanna show a "new/other" Viewmodel when a File is seleted in your  FileLoaderVM?

why dont you simply expose a event from your FileLoaderVM and subscribe to this event in your MainViewModel? if you do so your MainViewModel can then set the "new/other" Viewmodel to the ContentControl

Answer (score 1):

To change content of `ContentControl` you do not *load another user control*, but change value of `CurrentMainViewElementViewModel` (to which `ContentControl.Content` is bound) to a new ViewModel, which will load another `UserControl` (defined in `DataTemplate` same way as `FileLoaderVM` is).

This looks like a job for main ViewModel (where `CurrentMainViewElementViewModel` is located).

Easiest solution is to provide a method in that ViewModel

```
public Switch()
{
    CurrentMainViewElementViewModel = SomeViewModel;
}
```

and call this method from `FileLoaderVM`.